# How to apply a Unity script to several layers?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm trying to find a way to select objects in VR.

When a certain object is clicked upon a certain code will run telling what to do - such as quit the app.

Right now, the code runs to see whether an object has the layer *'Interactable'*, but how do I set my code up to check for more layers?

In the code, I've already tried setting up a check for more masks than just the *'Interactable'* mask.

```
private void ProcessTouchpadDown()
    {
        if (!m_CurrentObject)
            return;

        Interactable interactable = m_CurrentObject.GetComponent<Interactable>();
        interactable.Pressed();
    }
}
```

Upon the code above, the code below will run.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Interactable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Pressed()
    {
        //This code will run when an object with the 'interactable' layer is clicked. 
    }
}
```

I expect that when I add another layer mask I can just add it to the `ProcessTouchDown` and make a copy of the `interactable.pressed();` to apply different functions when an object is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layer masks in Unity are [bit flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types). You can use this to your advantage and iterate over the layers you want to check by bit shifting them.

```
    LayerMask layer = LayerMask.GetMask("Layer A", "Layer B", "Layer C");
    Interactable interactable = currentObject.GetComponent<Interactable>();

    //Checks if interactable's layer is contained within the layermask
    if (layer == (layer | (1 << interactable.gameObject.layer))) 
        interactable.Pressed();
```